# Use cases for AWS Glue with its current limitations on Python libraries

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

What are the best use cases where I can use AWS Glue services in ETL with its limitations on Python packages support?

> According to AWS Glue Documentation:
>
> Only pure Python libraries can be used. Libraries that rely on C
>   extensions, such as the pandas Python Data Analysis Library, are not
>   yet supported.

I have attempted some ETL jobs, run using AWS Glue, and I packaged some libraries such as Pandas, Holidays, etc. as a separate zip file and tried as well, but the jobs failed due these libraries (ImportError: Pandas)?

AWS do not have any ETA for providing the support for such libraries in the near future?

Or, is it too early to use AWS Glue, given that limitations on the python libraries being a major block now?

Comment: Yeah, which we could get an update on this.. Glue seems like the perfect fit for a large number of use cases if only we can get full python support.. Basically Lambda code functionality with Glue over it..